# Oracle sqlplus line size

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

In the SQLplus, why I set the line size to max (32767), it still out of format. how to fix it ?

```
select * from user_tables
TABLE_NAME                     TABLESPACE_NAME                CLUSTER_NAME                   IOT_NAME                       STATUS     PCT_FREE   PCT_U
_TRANS  MAX_TRANS INITIAL_EXTENT NEXT_EXTENT MIN_EXTENTS MAX_EXTENTS PCT_INCREASE  FREELISTS FREELIST_GROUPS LOG B   NUM_ROWS    BLOCKS EMPTY_BLOCKS  A
  CHAIN_CNT AVG_ROW_LEN AVG_SPACE_FREELIST_BLOCKS NUM_FREELIST_BLOCKS DEGREE    INSTANCES  CACHE TABLE_LO SAMPLE_SIZE LAST_ANAL PAR IOT_TYPE     T S NE
_ ROW_MOVE GLO USE DURATION       SKIP_COR MON CLUSTER_OWNER                  DEPENDEN COMPRESS COMPRESS_FOR       DRO REA
```

Comment: pls show the sqlplus commands used

Comment: What's "out of format"?  And keep in mind that if you're running this from a command console (e.g. Windows Command Prompt), the console will wrap your lines regardless.  Spool it to a file and you'll see the effect of your line length setting, which will be A LOT of whitespace characters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Made this as a comment above, but submitting as an answer here:

If you're running this from a command console (e.g. Windows Command Prompt), the console will wrap your lines regardless of your `LINESIZE`. Spool it to a file and you'll see the effect of your line length setting, which will be A LOT of whitespace characters.

Comment: "which will be A LOT of whitespace characters" unless you `set trimspool on`.

Answer (score 4):

```
set lines 9999
set trimspool on
spool myfile.txt
select * from user_tables;
spool off
```

Bring myfile.txt into an editor, columns will "line up".  set trimspool on will get rid of the trailing white space that is confusing you even more.

Answer (score 2):

what is the exact command that you are trying to execute in sql*plus?

It should be `SET LINESIZE ###`

Setting your linesize to 32767 columns is mighty wide, is that you are intending?